# Empty value inserted

Tags: mysql, insert

I observed that a few values are getting saved as empty in mysql table and the values are as follows. What should be done to save these values?

Comment: Do you actually want *those* column names? They sure can be used, but it could be a hassle to write SQL thenafter.

Comment: to add to @TheImpaler 's comment.. Using utf8 as column name is asking for trouble, some programming lauguages C# as example will not handle utf8 columns names correctly and might resolve into getting bugs..

Comment: I think he wants to store those values in a column called name, not use those values as column names.

Comment: Exactly @fancyPants

Comment: Actually its not problem with mysql. I just tried to insert these names with tsql and were saved properly. The problem is happening when I use eloquent.